# Convert a column vector with values in {1,...,K} to a K-column matrix with a 1 in the appropriate column

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave, vectorization

Say I have a vector `y` like

```
 2
 4
 3
10
```

and I want to obtain a matrix like

```
0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
```

What's the simplest/cleanest/"best" way of doing this in octave/matlab? I came up with:

```
repmat(y, 1, 10) == repmat(1:10, 4, 1)
```

Anyone have a better approach than this? It makes sense to me after having thought about it but I feel like it's a bit hard to parse for someone reading the code (though idk, I'm relatively new to vectorization, and a lot of vectorized code feels like that to me).

Comment: So by "better," you mean "easier to read?"

Comment: @RobertHarvey I suppose, unless this is only the case at the expense of something else that's important (eg, efficiency). I'm new to octave so I'm mostly just wondering how someone more familiar with it would implement this

Comment: @alecbenzer don't `repmat` here... extremely memory wasting. use `sparse` to represent your result if you can...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want your result to be `sparse` you can simply

```
n = numel( y ); % number of rows in resulting matrix
k = max(y(:)); % if you do not know k (num of columns) in advance
U = sparse( 1:n, y, 1, n, k );
```

If you want your result to be a full matrix

```
U = zeros( n, k );
U( sub2ind([n k], 1:n, y ) ) = 1;
```